# Woocommerce current endpoint page titles in my account template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working with woo-commerce user dashboard template.

I need to print the title of current endpoint instead of `the_title();`.

following image snapshot of

DOMIAN.com/my-account/orders/. there should be page title as **"My Order"** but it's "My Account".

Same requirement for other endpoint titles too.

Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original order of the My Account menu items can be seen in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-account-functions.php

```
/**
 * Get My Account menu items.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 * @return array
 */
function wc_get_account_menu_items() {
 return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array(
 'dashboard' => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
 'orders' => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
 'downloads' => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
 'edit-address' => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
 'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
 'edit-account' => __( 'Account Details', 'woocommerce' ),
 'customer-logout' => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
 ) );
}
```

You can change the order of these endpoints by using the **woocommerce_account_menu_items** filter, you can also change the list item title with the same filter.

```
<?php
function wpb_woo_my_account_order() {
    $myorder = array(
        'my-custom-endpoint' => __( 'My Stuff', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-account'       => __( 'Change My Details', 'woocommerce' ),
        'dashboard'          => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
        'orders'             => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
        'downloads'          => __( 'Download MP4s', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-address'       => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
        'payment-methods'    => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
        'customer-logout'    => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $myorder;
}
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'wpb_woo_my_account_order' );
```

One of the limitations with changing the list item title is that it won’t change the entry-title.

One way around changing the entry-title of the WooCommerce custom endpoint is to use the_title filter with the in_the_loop conditional.

```
<?php
/*
 * Change the entry title of the endpoints that appear in My Account Page - WooCommerce 2.6
 * Using the_title filter
 */
function wpb_woo_endpoint_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) && in_the_loop() ) { // add your endpoint urls
        $title = "Download MP3s"; // change your entry-title
    }
    elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = "My Orders";
    }
    elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = "Change My Details";
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpb_woo_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick response, i already saw this the_title filter somewhere but that time didn't notice the in_the_loop check... however it's working with a light change in the if condition...

thank you so much ArtiJi

Comment: Its all my pleasure. Welcome

Comment: This doesn't work unless you remove the `in_the_loop` check.

Comment: I think `woocommerce_endpoint_{$endpoint}_title` is safer way to chang a headline and a page title.

Answer (score 6):

### Display endpoint title

```php
<?php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wc_page_endpoint_title' );
the_title( '<h1 class="page-title mb-4">', '</h1>' );
?>
```

[wc_page_endpoint_title](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_page_endpoint_title)

### Bonus - endpoint document title

```php
/**
 * Generates account page titles
 *
 * @see wc_page_endpoint_title
 *
 * @param string $title Current title.
 * @return string
 */
function vralle_generate_wc_endpoint_title( string $title ): string {
    $action   = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['action'] ) ) : '';
    $endpoint = WC()->query->get_current_endpoint();
    $ep_title = $endpoint ? WC()->query->get_endpoint_title( $endpoint, $action ) : '';
    if ( ! empty( $ep_title ) ) {
        return $ep_title;
    }

    return $title;
}
/**
 * Filters document title.
 *
 * @param array $title The document title parts.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function vralle_document_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_page() && function_exists( 'is_wc_endpoint_url' ) && is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
    $title['title'] = vralle_generate_wc_endpoint_title( $title['title'] );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'vralle_document_title );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this outdated but this code below has been tested and works...

```
function wc_custom_end_point_page_title( $title ) {
  global $wp_query;

  $is_endpoint = isset( $wp_query->query_vars['my-custom-endpoint'] );

  if ( $is_endpoint && ! is_admin() && is_main_query() && in_the_loop() && is_account_page() ) {

    $title = __( 'Custom Endpoint Title', 'woocommerce' );

    remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wc_custom_end_point_page_title' );
  }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wc_custom_end_point_page_title' );
```